# Series of books about aliens with psychic powers, maybe called "The Others"?

Tags: books, aliens, story-identification

I read a series of books way back in the 70s about a group of beings from another planet. The creatures had psychic powers but were trying to live in human society. I don't know the name of the series, but I think maybe it was called "The Others."

Comment: "The People" stories by Zenna Henderson?

Comment: I'll check that out. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: The 'People' stories have recently been re-published in one volume 'Ingathering'.

Comment: Have checked out your suggestions and it is indeed "The People" series by Zenna Henderson. Even found a you tube copy of a made for TV movie that had (pre StarTrek) William Shatner as a doctor/vet. Not how i I am ordering the "Ingathering" for re-reading the series

Answer (score 5):

As confirmed by the OP in a comment, this refers to "[The People](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?21857)" stories by Zenna Henderson.

> ... her series concerning the history of "The People", humanoid beings
> from a faraway planet who are forced to emigrate to Earth when their
> home world is destroyed by a natural disaster. Scattered mostly
> throughout the American Southwest during their landing before 1900,
> they are set apart by their desire to preserve their home culture,
> including their religious and spiritual beliefs. Their unusual
> abilities include telepathy, telekinesis, prophecy, and healing, which
> they call the "Signs and Persuasions". The People suppress their
> unusual abilities as they attempt to integrate into human life.

([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zenna_Henderson))

There are several other questions about "The People" but none appear to have accepted answers.